# How can I style table data differently according to the cell value?

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I try to stylize a cell data according to it's value but not working.
The StatusPorumbei model has many objects stored and for each value, I wand another badge class.How can I take each value in StatusPorumbei and giving to it other class? First is the model, next is the template and last is the view function.

```
class StatusPorumbei(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Status"
    verbose_name_plural = "Statusuri"
    ordering = ['status']

class Porumbei(models.Model):

    id_porumbel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    serie_inel = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    anul = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False, blank=False)

    culoare = models.ForeignKey(CuloriPorumbei, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    culoare_ochi = models.ForeignKey(CuloriOchi, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    sex = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ecloziune = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    rasa = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    linie = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    nume = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    tata = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)

    mama = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)

    compartiment = models.ForeignKey(Compartimente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    status = models.ForeignKey(StatusPorumbei, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

<tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
        <tr class="table-active">
            <td>{{ item.serie_inel }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.anul }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.culoare }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sex }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.compartiment }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.tata }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.mama }}</td>
    {% if item.status in sts %}
        {% if "Activ" %}
            <td><span class="badge badge-success">{{ item.status }}</span></td>
        {% elif "Reproducător" %}
            <td><span class="badge badge-indigo">{{ item.status }}</span></td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="mr-25" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Editare">
            <i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

def dashboard(request):
items = Porumbei.objects.all()
sts = StatusPorumbei.objects.all()
context = {
    'items' : items,
    'sts' : sts
}
template = loader.get_template("dashboard.html")
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query on the `item.status`

```
    {% if  item.status.status == "Activ" %}
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">{{ item.status }}</span></td>
    {% elif  item.status.status == "Reproducător" %}
        <td><span class="badge badge-indigo">{{ item.status }}</span></td>
    {% else %}
        <td><span>{{ item.status.status }}</span></td>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I've tried this but doesn't display the Status column.

Comment: Then it isn't equal to either value.  Edited above to include an `{% else %}` and to use the `CharField` rather than object